# substract each two row in one column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I found this problem bellow while executing the code bellow on google colab it works normaly

```
df['temps'] = df['temps'].view(int).div(1e9).diff().fillna(0).abs()
print(df)
```

but while using jupyter notebook localy the error bellow appears

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df3['rebounds'] = pd.Series(df3['temps'].view(int).div(1e9).diff().fillna(0))

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:818, in Series.view(self, dtype)
    815 # self.array instead of self._values so we piggyback on PandasArray
    816 #  implementation
    817 res_values = self.array.view(dtype)
--> 818 res_ser = self._constructor(res_values, index=self.index)
    819 return res_ser.__finalize__(self, method="view")

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:442, in Series.__init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    440     index = default_index(len(data))
    441 elif is_list_like(data):
--> 442     com.require_length_match(data, index)
    444 # create/copy the manager
    445 if isinstance(data, (SingleBlockManager, SingleArrayManager)):

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py:557, in require_length_match(data, index)
    553 """
    554 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    555 """
    556 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 557     raise ValueError(
    558         "Length of values "
    559         f"({len(data)}) "
    560         "does not match length of index "
    561         f"({len(index)})"
    562     )

ValueError: Length of values (830) does not match length of index (415)
```

any suggetions to resolve this !!

Comment: What is the data type of the original df3['temps'] (specifically, how many bytes is that data type)?

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason you have chosen to use view()?

Comment: the data type of df3['temps'] is ```datetime64[ns]``` i use view to convert the dates to numbers, .div(1e9) to convert the resulting nanoseconds into seconds

Comment: @constantstranger but the same code is running on colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to get this to work:

```py
df3['rebounds'] = pd.Series(df3['temps'].view('int64').diff().fillna(0).div(1e9))
```

... or:

```py
df3['rebounds'] = pd.Series(df3['temps'].astype('int64').diff().fillna(0).div(1e9))
```

For the following sample input:

```
df3.dtypes:

temps    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

df3:

       temps
0 2022-01-01
1 2022-01-02
2 2022-01-03
```

... both of the above code samples give this output:

```
df3.dtypes:

temps       datetime64[ns]
rebounds           float64
dtype: object

df3:

       temps  rebounds
0 2022-01-01       0.0
1 2022-01-02   86400.0
2 2022-01-03   86400.0
```

The issue is probably that `view()` essentially reinterprets the raw data of the existing series as a different data type. For this to work, according to the `Series.view()` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) (see also the `numpy.ndarray.view()` [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)) the data types must have the same number of bytes. Since the original data is `datetime64`, your code specifying `int` as the argument to view() may not have met this requirement. Explicitly specifying `int64` should meet it. Or, using `astype()` instead of `view()` with int64 will also work.

As to why this works in colab and not in jupyter notebook, I can't say. Perhaps they are using different versions of pandas and numpy which treat `int` differently.

I do know that in my environment, if I try the following:

```py
df3['rebounds'] = pd.Series(df3['temps'].astype('int').diff().fillna(0).div(1e9))
```

... then I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

This suggests that `int` means `int32`. It would be interesting to see if this works on colab.